# installing rpm packages inside of a virtual python environment (virtualenv or pyvenv) on rhel 6 with no internet access

Tags: python, django, pip, rhel

My RHEL server only has access to packages that are pre-approved by my IT. I'm developing an Python application that will be hosted on this server. For now, I've managed to build the latest version of python at a different location (/usr/local/bin). I'm able create virtual environments to isolate it from the rest of the system.

Now, I need to install packages using pip in the environment to get the app to work eg. Django. Since every access to the internet has been disabled by IT, I cannot do pip install package_name. Well, I can but it tries to download the package from the internet and times out. When I download the rpm of the django package and try to install it in the virtual environment, it fails:

```
(envtest) [root@arlwebimgakp02 envtest]# rpm -ivh python3-django-1.7.2-1.fc22.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        /usr/bin/python3 is needed by python3-django-1.7.2-1.fc22.noarch
        python(abi) = 3.4 is needed by python3-django-1.7.2-1.fc22.noarch
        python-django-bash-completion = 1.7.2-1.fc22 is needed by python3-django-1.7.2-1.fc22.noarch
        python3 is needed by python3-django-1.7.2-1.fc22.noarch
```

So it looks like the rpm install is looking for dependencies from the universal install of python (2.6.6) instead of the separately compiled 3.4.3 which is used in the virtual environment. Can I even do this? Can I install an rpm package to just a virtual environment? How else can I get my python packages to install in my virtual environments without internet access to the server?

Comment: Interesting problem. It seems that it might be possible to install "Python" rpm package by unpacking rpm files.

Answer (score 0):

RPM is a package manager at system level. It will check it's internal database for dependencies. Does not check if the executable *python* exist but if the package *python* exist.

You need to download Django-1.8.tar.gz, copy to linux machine and

```
pip install Django-1.8.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convince your IT department that python packages are a good thing, just like rpms. Then, you can build a directory of the packages you want by downloading directly from pypi.python.org or by using pip like:

```
pip install --download=/path/to/pypi/repo django
```

Then, in your virtualenv you do

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/pypi/repo django
```

Because your IT department is helpful and enlightened, you can even convince them to install a pypi cache such as [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) to make your deployments to your many coworkers that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you cannot install an RPM in a virtualenv. A virtualenv only affects Python packages installed by `pip`.

What you can do is use another computer that does have internet access to download the Python packages you want and upload those to the server to install. You can specify the Python version the packages are for and even use a requirements file if you have one. If, for example, you wanted to install the latest version of Django for Python 3.5, you would do the following:

```
# On your machine with internet access
pip download --python-version "3.5" --only-binary=:all: Django
```

This will download a series of `.whl` files. Upload all of these to your server, then run this command in your virtualenv on the server:

```
pip install *.whl
```